# How to create a trigger on table to update field after one hour if a specific value have been set

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My database stores the parking status information [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPJjL.jpg)
The status field has three values (0 for empty, 1 for occupied and 2 for waiting)
If the parking status remains 2 for 1 hour I want to set it to 0 and set the username field to null.

Is there any way to do it with triggers.

Comment: Triggers can only be invoked by update/insert/delete. You need a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably looking to create a [`Event`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) like

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY HOUR 
DO
UPDATE mytable 
SET status = 0, username = null
where status = 2;
```

Comment: MySQL has events? **How cool is that?** Do you know how many cronjobs I have and now can get rid of? Thx!

Comment: Whoa, didn't know about those events.

Comment: This looks nice. However, should there be an extra condition in `WHERE` that checks the time when the status has changed to 2? Does the table have timestamp for the latest change? @tuhaishi